# Pandas get days in a between two two dates from a particular month

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a `pandas` dataframe with three columns. A start and end date and a month.

I would like to add a column for how many days within the month are between the two dates. I started doing something with `apply`, the `calendar` library and some math, but it started to get really complex. I bet `pandas` has a simple solution, but am struggling to find it.

Input:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[['2017-01-01', '2017-06-01', '2016-01-01'],
                         ['2015-03-02', '2016-02-10', '2016-02-01'],
                         ['2011-01-02', '2018-02-10', '2016-03-01']],
                  columns=['start date', 'end date date', 'Month'])
```

Desired Output:

```
   start date end date date       Month  Days in Month
0  2017-01-01    2017-06-01  2016-01-01              0
1  2015-03-02    2016-02-10  2016-02-01             10
2  2011-01-02    2018-02-10  2016-03-01             31
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a solution:
get a date list by `pd.date_range` between `start` and `end` dates, and then check how many date has the same `year` and `month` with the target month.

```
def overlap(x):
    md = pd.to_datetime(x[2])
    cand =  [(ad.year, ad.month) for ad in pd.date_range(x[0], x[1])]
    return len([x for x in cand if x ==(md.year, md.month)])
df1["Days in Month"]= df1.apply(overlap, axis=1)
```

You'll get:

```
   start date end date date       Month  Days in Month
0  2017-01-01    2017-06-01  2016-01-01              0
1  2015-03-02    2016-02-10  2016-02-01             10
2  2011-01-02    2018-02-10  2016-03-01             31
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your cell to datetime by

`df = df.applymap(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))`

Then find intersection days with function

```
def intersectionDaysInMonth(start, end, month):
    end_month = month.replace(month=month.month + 1)
    if month <= start <= end_month:
        return end_month - start
    if month <= end <= end_month:
        return end - month
    if start <= month < end_month <= end:
        return end_month - month

    return pd.to_timedelta(0)
```

Then apply

```
df['Days in Month'] = df.apply(lambda row: intersectionDaysInMonth(*row).days, axis=1)
```